# Spring Security using HTTP headers

Tags: security, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, http-headers

I am trying to add security to my Spring Boot application. My current application is using REST controllers and every time I get a `GET` or `POST` request I read the HTTP header to retrieve the user and password in order to validate them against the properties file I have all my users stored. I want to change this to using Spring Security and this is what I got so far:

```java
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN").build());
    }
}
```

How can I tell the `configure` method that the user credentials are to be retrieved from the header and not a login form?

Comment: Do you mean basic authentication with `Authentication` header?

Comment: What HTTP header do you mean, what's the name of the header?

Answer (score 9):

the minimal code addition is to define a filter and add it to the security configuration, smth like

**XHeaderAuthenticationFilter.java**

```java
@Component
public class XHeaderAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String xAuth = request.getHeader("X-Authorization");

        User user = findByToken(xAuth);

        if (user == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Token invalid");
        } else {
            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    //need to implement db user validation...
    private User findByToken(String token) {
        if (!token.equals("1234"))
            return null;

        final User user = new User(
                "username",
                "password",
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));

        return user;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new XHeaderAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
}
```

another approach is to use spring's `AOP` to define annotation of some logic to perform before entering the annotated controller method

Comment: Interesting example. In my code I check for the existence of a security context at the beginning of the filter to avoid accessing the DB for each request. Of course I also allow session creation.

Comment: @Pino , yes, that would be more efficient, keep in mind that usually when using headers auth it comes hand in hand with stateless... so basically there isn't any session you can get from the context... but this code is a minimal and can be extended vastly...

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid using default `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` since it gets client supplied username and password from the parameters of your request and you really need to get them from the headers.

So, you should write a custom `AuthenticationFilter` extending referred `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to change its behaviour to fit your requirements:

```java
public class HeaderUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

  public HeaderUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
    super();
    this.setFilterProcessesUrl("/**");
    this.setPostOnly(false);
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#obtainPassword(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
   */
  @Override
  protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getHeader(this.getPasswordParameter());
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#obtainUsername(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
   */
  @Override
  protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getHeader(this.getPasswordParameter());
  }

}
```

This filter example extends `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` listens to every request and gets `username` and `password` from headers instead of `parameters`.

Then you should change the configuration this way, setting your filter in the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` position:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterAt(
                new HeaderUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), 
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

}
```

Comment: OK thanks but how do I read the role now in my properties file now?

Comment: Please edit your post including your properties file structure. You must build a `UserDetailsService` which reads the entries from your file

Answer (score 1):

In memory authentication would serve your purpose

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user1").password("password1").roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("user2").password("password2").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.httpBasic();   
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

In spring boot app you can add  below to application.properties

```
security.user.name=user
security.user.password=password
```

It will do rest of the thing like getting it from header and validation
for more visit https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have more than one user (I just posted on as an example)

Comment: see this you can create your own  AuthenticationManager  and add user accounts to it https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html