# Can spring security parse headers and verify authentication information?

Tags: spring, rest, web-applications, spring-security

Spring Security is commonly used for authentication and authorization of web applications and web services. While spring can validate users based on credentials_id (user id) and credentails_secret (password) passed through web forms.
What I am looking at is
1) can spring work when these userid and password are passed through http headers.
2) **on subsequent requests can spring validate user based on a session id (some thing like jsessionid) passed through http headers?**

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. yes. Read the docs and check the components involved.

Comment: Am relatively new to spring - could you pass the links to docs referring to this subject.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `spring-security` module in your project.

1. passing username and password via http-headers for every request is stateless basic-authentication. Check this [example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication)
2. You can do a stateful authentication: authenticate once, maintain the session.
   Check this [sample](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session)

Answer (score 1):

So, you should write a custom AuthenticationFilter extending referred UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

Checkout:
[Spring Security using HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111074/spring-security-using-http-headers)